# VS Code extension for more customizable comment visualization

Tags: visual-studio-code, documentation

Does anybody know a good VS Code extension for visualizing comments? Right now I am using the default VS Code stuff together with Doxygen Documentation Generator extension. It looks a bit like this :

[image: 1]

But I would still like some more customizability. This could be creating headings, links, bold text etc. Maybe some extension which would take markdown language and convert it to some of these popups dynamically.

This may be a bit much to ask for, but I just want some nice documentation. Any suggestions?

**(I am primarily using C++, if that matters)**